# How can i open ng bootstrap dropdown menu by default

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

Am trying to make the dropdown menu to show by default

```
<img src="assets/images/small-images/1.png" width="32px" id="dropdownForm1" ngbDropdownToggle>
<div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownForm1"                                    style="width: 200px; border-radius: 0px; margin-top: 28px;">
    <app-mega-menu></app-mega-menu>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

set Input `open` to `true`

check out this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5hv17y) may this will helps you!

`open` Defines whether or not the dropdown menu is opened initially.

Type: `boolean`

Default value: `false`

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block" [open]="true">


</div>
```

Comment: `open="'true'"` will pass the string `"'true'"` as input. This will work only because `"'true'"` is truthy, but it's neither good to look nor correct. I think [open]="true" is more correct

Comment: As a proof, if you pass `open="'false'"` or `open="'banana'"` it works the same. Because `true` has no particular meaning there